# Installing Jupyter Extension, Failure to Enable 'nbextension'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm posting this question as I couldn't solve this problem upon multiple sifting/troubeshooting on SO, etc.

I have all the below packages successfully installed, a `pip list`, `conda list` shows:

[image]

The code I used to install the packages:

```
!pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
!pip install https://github.com/ipythoncontrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tarball/master
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

I also tried the last line with

`jupyter contrib nbextensions install --sys-prefix --skip-running-check`

I end up getting error:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-1c0e089b301b>", line 1
    jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When running on terminal in Administrator mode, I get:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install jupyter_contib_nbextensions
Collecting jupyter_contib_nbextensions
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter_contib_nbextensions (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jupyter_contib_nbextensions
```

What am I missing here? I also tried upgrading `jupyter, ipython`; thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note to help update what is shown here. The `%pip` and `%conda` magics were added the year this was posted to avoid the shortcomings of using an exclamation point with `pip` and `conda`. Use of `%pip` and `%conda` magics inside a notebook will now insure what is issued happens in the environment backing the notebook. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the recently-added magic commands. In short, for a better experience don't use an exclamation point in combination with `pip` or `conda`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. You have to prefix it by ! when running on the notebook. Hence the invalid syntax.

---

```
!jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

2. Typo on what you’re trying to install. Hence the error. contib should be contrib:

---

```
python -m pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Number 1 solved my problem with the syntax error, but I had to run number 2 with `!` too. Try it as follows:
`!python -m pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

Answer (score 0):

## add !

i was copy pasting the commands from youtube video. so didnt checked properly
i was running

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

and this was giving me error
but there should be a "!" on start.
it should be

```
!jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```